# Syncing Local config to repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push, git-config

I'm having trouble with my local .git/config settings pushing to bitbucket. I've been trying to set `ignorecase` to false, then push up the repo. When I reclone my repo, `ignorecase` is true again.

```
git rm tempfile
git commit -m "removing temp"
git config core.ignorecase false --local
git push
cd ..
rm -rf folder/
git clone 
cd folder/
git config -l
```

I've also tried `--set-upstream`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Everything from `.git` directory (well, not literally everything, but *everything except the index*) is only stored locally and never sent back to the server.

So you just cannot do that.

PS: how about just using consistent filenames at first, not fix it with `ignorecase`?